# How to stop/kill command task in my jobs which running continuously in IICS

Tags: informatica-cloud, iics, iics-di

Command task is running continuously if i stopped Task flow manually in My jobs. How to stop this command task. Also, if I run new task flow with command task, the status is showing queued unable to stop these command task.

[image: 1]

I have stopped Main task flow, but still command task is running. I want to stop these command task due to this other command tasks are not running the status is showing queued or running for all time.

Comment: You need to physically stop/abort the command from the IICS node( where the command is running). Informatica sometime couldnt control/abort the command task thats running in OS. You can ask administrator of the OS as well.

Comment: There is no option to stop/abort the command task physically, as screenshot shows only log file, other than log file no other options available. As the batch file contain execution of console application(C#) with multiple arguments.

Comment: do you know which node iics is running ? IICS  is normally installed in some node/server. do you know where it is ? can you login there?

Comment: yes i know, it is installed in server. I logged in server and stopped background services which are related to me through task manager. Thanks.